# What type of component is the AMTEX ST033?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I want to know the IC used for this Nintendo 64 heartbeat detector peripheral. As seen in the image is an ST033 AMTEX (9836 which is probably a serial number) but a Google search won't show any relevant datasheet for the IC. Any suggestions would be welcome as I'd like to look at the datasheet (if it's available).

[image]

Comment: Hi, Re: "*9836 which is probably a serial number*" Just FYI it's likely to be a date code - 1998 week 36. That 4-digit format is a common one for IC manufacturing dates. || Also, although it doesn't answer your question (sorry) but for those readers who might be interested, there is some background on the "Bio Sensor" accessory which included that PCB along with a fingertip sensor, described on [this](https://www.raphnet.net/divers/n64_bio_sensor/index_en.php) webpage.

Comment: Those are some very interestingly packaged electrolytic capacitors! o:  However, I'd wager that ST033 chip is just a customized microcontroller. Not a clue which particular one, however. Odds are it's mask-programmed or one-time programmable, like many of the era were.

Comment: @SamGibson interesting, it never occurred to me that it could be a date code but it certainly makes sense!